# Handle promise rejection in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am using to create backend `NestJs` library. In my code i have used a `guard` to check if my token is still active:

```
import {Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, HttpException, HttpStatus} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(
        context: ExecutionContext,
    ): any | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const token =  request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
            try {
                const decoded = jwt.verify(token, '123');
                console.log(decoded)
                return true
            } catch(e) {
                console.log('tkn error', e)
                throw new HttpException('User unauthorized', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
    }
}
```

also i have this `service` that check the refresh token:

```
import {HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import {InjectRepository} from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import {User} from "../entities/user.entity";
import {Repository} from "typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class RefreshService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(User)
        private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
    ) {

    }

    async refresh(res, req) {
        const userId =  req.headers['userid'];
        const refreshToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({
            where: {
                id: userId,
            },
        });

        if (!refreshToken) {
            throw new HttpException('User unauthorized', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        jwt.verify(refreshToken, 'refresh', function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                throw new HttpException('User unauthorized rt', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            } else {
                const token = jwt.sign({foo: 'bar'}, '123', {expiresIn: '55s'});

                res.send({
                    message: "You are logged in",
                    timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
                    token: token,
                    user: user
                });
            }
        });

        console.log('refresh', refreshToken)
        res.send(refreshToken)
    }
}
```

Even if i used `try catch` i get the error in console:

```
[0] (node:1444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
[0] (node:1444) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

also i get:

```
[0] (node:15492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Question: Which are my mistakes in the code above?
How to solve them?

Comment: You throw `HttpExeption`s you are never catching (at least not in the code you are showing us). In the first snipped you throw a exception inside the `catch` block. Where will that exception be catched?  And also in the second snippet, both exceptions (one before `verify`, the other in the callback of `verify`) are not catched anywhere.

Comment: Furthermore, once you reach `verify` in your second snippet and the callback of that `verify` doesn't throw, you are sending a response twice, once with `res.send(refreshToken)` and once with `res.send({ message: "You are logged in", ... `

Comment: And please use the code snippets only for code that is really executable and shows your error

Comment: @derpirscher, could you show please how to change the code? It will be very helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You throw some exeptions that aren't caught anywhere

```
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): any | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token =  request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, '123');
        console.log(decoded)
        return true
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('tkn error', e)
        //remove the exception here and just return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

Furthermore in your second snippet, you are calling `res.send(..)` for the same `res` object twice, which results in the `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]` you are seeing. Furthermore, you probably want some error handling also, when the user is not found ...

```
async refresh(res, req) {
    const userId =  req.headers['userid'];
    const refreshToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({
        where: {
            id: userId,
        },
    });

    if (user && refreshToken) {
        jwt.verify(refreshToken, 'refresh', function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                //remove the exception and send an appropriate response
                res.sendStatus(401);
            } else {
                const token = jwt.sign({foo: 'bar'}, '123', {expiresIn: '55s'});
                res.send({
                    message: "You are logged in",
                    timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
                    token: token,
                    user: user
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
      //if no user or no refreshToken is found 
      res.sendStatus(401); //send unauthorized status
    }
}
```

And just a hint for the security of the process: You should probably check somewhere, if `refreshToken` and `user` belong together. Otherwise, a user which has a valid `refreshToken` can login impersonating any other user ...

Comment: what is the difference between `res.sendStatus(401);` and `throw new HttpException('User unauthorized', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);`? Why the error does not appear when i write  `res.sendStatus(401);` ?

Comment: the first one sends a result back to the requesting client. the second one throws an exception which is never caught (and probably doesn't send a result back to the client)